# redmineにbacklogインストール時エラー

Tags: redmine

redmine3.2へpluginのbacklog1.0.0をインストールしようとすると下記のエラーが出ます。
解決策をおしえていただけますでしょうか。よろしくお願いします。

```
[root@localhost redmine]# bundle exec rake redmine:backlogs:install

[!] There was an error parsing `Gemfile`: 
[!] There was an error parsing `Gemfile`: You cannot specify the same     gem twice with different version requirements.
You specified: nokogiri (>= 1.6.7.1) and nokogiri (>= 0). Bundler     cannot continue.

 #  from /var/www/redmine/plugins/redmine_backlogs/Gemfile:13
 #  -------------------------------------------
 #  gem "icalendar"
 >  gem "nokogiri"
 #  gem "open-uri-cached"
 #  -------------------------------------------
. Bundler cannot continue.

 #  from /var/www/redmine/Gemfile:113
 #  -------------------------------------------
 #  Dir.glob File.expand_path("../plugins/*/{Gemfile,PluginGemfile}", __FILE__) do |file|
 >    eval_gemfile file
 #  end
 #  -------------------------------------------
```

追記

> Gemfileを修正してgem "nokogiri", "=>1.6.7.1"にするとどうでしょうか。
>
> 参考）
>   https://github.com/Hopebaytech/redmine_mail_reminder/issues/58

上記のよう修正しましたらまた違うエラーがでてしました。

```
 [picolit@localhost redmine]$ bundle exec rake redmine:backlogs:install
 Could not find gem 'capybara (~> 1.1.0)' in any of the gem sources
 listed in your Gemfile or available on this machine. Run bundle
 install to install missing gems.
```

Answer (score 1):

Gemfileを修正して`gem "nokogiri", "=>1.6.7.1"`にするとどうでしょうか。

参考）
https://github.com/Hopebaytech/redmine_mail_reminder/issues/58

Comment: ありがとうございます。上記のよう修正しましたらまた違うエラーがでてしました。

[picolit@localhost redmine]$ bundle exec rake redmine:backlogs:install
Could not find gem 'capybara (~> 1.1.0)' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile or available on this machine.
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.

Comment: コメントだと他の方が気が付きにくいので、変化が有った場合は 質問に追記してもらったほうが他のかたのコメントが付きやすくなりますよ。ともあれ つぎの点をためしてみるとどうでしょうか。
1. たまに（というか割りとといいますか）Rubygemsのサイトが繋がらない場合があるのでもう一度`bundle exec rake redmine:backlogs:install` 実行すると変化ありませんか。
2. 表示されたメッセージにしたがって操作すると解決するコとも多いので`bundle install`を実行してみる
3. Gemfile.lockを消してから `bundle install` してみる

Comment: ご丁寧にありがとうございます。質問に追記してみます。
使い勝手がわからずすいません。

Comment: 追記してくださったんですね。ありがとうございます。 ときに私がコメント差し上げた点は確認できましたでしょうか。